# Measurement phrase: "determined to 1 cm precisely", "centimeter-precision"

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I'm not perfectly sure about the stated phrase (or similar ones since I had to translate it). Does it mean

- +-1 cm, or
- +-0.5 cm?

I guess many people use it in the first way but only the latter will give a
range for our value that is exactly 1 cm.

Comment: It is not a very exact terminology. I think the best if we say, the [deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is 1 cm. Note, many independent probability variable sums together always to a normal distribution.

Comment: I would assume that it means your [uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_uncertainty) is $0.x$ cm, which I think is closer to the first statement.